# unable to find build script at c:\JmeterTest\build.xml

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am simply trying to run a jmeter test and get email from jenkins. Everytime my job fails and error message is unable to find build.xml.Below is the log

I went through all online help, specified ANT etc but nothing worked.

[JmeterTest] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1399437408540848331.bat

C:\JmeterTest>cd c:\Jmeter\bin

c:\Jmeter\bin>C:\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -n -t  C:\JmeterTest\JmeterTest.jmx -l C:\Results\JmeterTest.jtl -e -o C:\Results 
Creating summariser 
Created the tree successfully using C:\JmeterTest\JmeterTest.jmx
Starting the test @ Mon Aug 12 14:31:50 EDT 2019 (1565634710309)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary +   2259 in 00:00:09 =  250.9/s Avg:     4 Min:     1 Max:  2040 Err:  2257 (99.91%) Active: 2 Started: 3 Finished: 1
summary +  23846 in 00:00:30 =  794.9/s Avg:     2 Min:     0 Max:   115 Err: 23846 (100.00%) Active: 2 Started: 3 Finished: 1
summary =  26105 in 00:00:39 =  669.3/s Avg:     2 Min:     0 Max:  2040 Err: 26103 (99.99%)
summary +   9897 in 00:00:15 =  658.6/s Avg:     2 Min:     0 Max:    31 Err:  9897 (100.00%) Active: 0 Started: 3 Finished: 3
summary =  36002 in 00:00:54 =  666.3/s Avg:     2 Min:     0 Max:  2040 Err: 36000 (99.99%)
Tidying up ...    @ Mon Aug 12 14:32:45 EDT 2019 (1565634765028)
... end of run
ERROR: Unable to find build script at C:\JmeterTest\build.xml
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose one of the options:

1. [Running JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) (which works fine according to your Jenkins console output)
2. Running JMeter test via [Apache Ant](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/tags/v2_1_1/extras/JMeter%20Ant%20Task.html)

You seem to have both build steps so my expectation is that you just need to remove the "Ant" one or to properly configure it if you want to proceed with Ant. An example build.xml file can be found:

- Under "extras" folder of your JMeter installation
- Under "extras" folder of [JMeter Sources](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/extras/build.xml)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, it really helped. i removed Ant and getting build as good. As a next step i am trying to send html results in email which i am able to do by configuring smtp and Editable Email Notification , however i am getting report which points to location of my local jenkins host and clicking on link in my email shows page not found, which is obvious but how can i make it work?